# Given a date, how to find if it's the second or fourth Saturday of the month

Tags: ruby, date, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails application, I need to find if a given date is the second or fourth Saturday of the month. What's the efficient way to do this? Is there a gem I can use?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I have the beginning of the month, end of the month and their days. Working through it still.

Comment: "I have the beginning of the month, end of the month and their days. Working through it still." - Show us that code!! Please include your code in SO questions, you'll be much more likely to get help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Days 1 to 7 are week 0
- Days 8 to 14 are week 1
- Days 15 to 21 are week 2
- Days 22 to 28 are week 3

To get the week id, we can calculate `(date.day-1)/7`. Since the id is zero-based, the second and fourth saturdays have an odd week id :

```
def second_or_fourth_saturday?(date)
  date.saturday? && ((date.day - 1) / 7).odd?
end
```

Answer (score 4):

The second Saturday has to be in the day range 8-14, and the fourth in the day range 22-28. So I think this should work

```
def second_or_forth_saturday?(date)
  return false unless date.saturday?
  (8..14).include?(date.day) || (22..28).include?(date.day)
end
```

Comment: last 2 lines could be `(8..14).include?(date.day) || (22..28).include?(date.day)`

Comment: `date.wday == 6` can be expressed as `date.saturday?`

Comment: Thank you Eric Duminil & Stefan. You are both right, and I have updated my answer as a result

Answer (score 2):

```
def fourth_saturday?(date)
  saturdays = (date.beginning_of_month..date.end_of_month).select { |date| date.wday == 6 }
  [satudays.second, saturdays.fourth].include?(date)
end
```

1. create a month dates range
2. select Saturdays
3. see, if second or fourth Saturday is equal to date

As @Stefan kindly suggested, the first line of the method could be written as follows (using [`all_month`](http://apidock.com/rails/DateAndTime/Calculations/all_month)):

```
saturdays = date.all_month.select(&:saturday?)
```

References:

Comment: `saturdays = date.all_month.select(&:saturday?)` would fit into one line ;-)

Comment: `saturdays.first ` and `saturdays.third` are not equivalent to `saturdays[1]` and `saturdays[3]`

Comment: `[satudays.first, saturdays.third].include?(date)` wait, what?

Comment: Guys I was somehow  100% sure we are talking about first and third Saturday... man, editing